# filter object data angularjs

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I want to filter my inventory by barcode, can i do something like this? The main point here is,  if the barcode  what i am passing equals to inventory[i] barcode(in server), then change `$scope.inventories` to only those which barcodes match. And then $scope.inventories only will consist of matching barcode inventories.

Got some crazy errors. Any help , how to filter object data?

```
$scope.inventories = new Inventory().query().$object;

$scope.filter = function(barcode) {
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
            if($scope.inventories[i].barcode == barcode){
                $scope.inventories = $scope.inventories[i];
            } 
        }
    };
```

Template

```
<ul ng-repeat="inventory in inventories">
    <li><a href="" ng-click="filter(inventory.barcode)">{{inventory.barcode}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create different variable name for filtered items

```
    $scope.filter = function(barcode) {
        var filtered = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
            if($scope.inventories[i].barcode == barcode){
                filtered.push($scope.inventories[i]);
            } 
        }
        $scope.filtered_inventories = filtered;
    };
```

Comment: maybe you can help me out here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712486/filter-objects-matching-details

Answer (score 0):

Define a filter:

```
$scope.filterByBarcode = function(list, barcode) {
    return list.filter(function(item){
        return item.barcode === barcode;
    });
};
```

Filter in the list at ng-repeat:

```
<ul ng-repeat="inventory in filterByBarcode(inventories, barcode)">
    <li><a href="" ng-click="inventory">{{inventory.barcode}}</a></li>  <!-- Not sure if this is what you want to display --> 
</ul>
```