# filter objects matching details

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

Functions works fine, they filter inventory by barcode, and manufacturer. I want to make it like default angularjs filtering. If I choose manufacturer - LG and barcode - 112 and if they don't match, then it shouldn't display anything.

But for now it displays separately, when i click on filter function it filters barcode when on filter2 function filter manufacturer

```
$scope.filter = function(barcode) {
            var filtered = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
                if($scope.inventories[i].barcode == barcode){
                    filtered.push($scope.inventories[i]);
                } 
            }
            $scope.filtered_inventories = filtered;
        };

        $scope.filter2 = function(manufacturer) {
            var filtered = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
                if($scope.inventories[i].manufacturer == manufacturer){
                    filtered.push($scope.inventories[i]);
                } 
            }
            $scope.filtered_inventories = filtered;
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    $scope.filter = function (barcode, manufacturer) {
        var filtered = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inventories.length; i++){
            if($scope.inventories[i].barcode == barcode || $scope.inventories[i].manufacturer == manufacturer){
                filtered.push($scope.inventories[i]);
            } 
        }
        $scope.filtered_inventories = filtered;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a more general way of filtering:

```
$scope.filterByBarcode = function(list, key, value) {
    return list.filter(function(item){
        return item[key] === value;
    });
};
```

And when you filter you could call:

```
$scope.filtered_inventories = $scope.filter($scope.filter($scope.inventories, 'barcode', 112), 'manufacturer', 'LG')
```

But to simplify that you could create a function:

```
$scope.filterByBarcodeAndManufacturer = function(barcode, manufacturer) {
    $scope.filtered_inventories = 
        $scope.filter($scope.filter($scope.inventories, 'barcode', barcode), 'manufacturer', manufacturer);  
}
```

Comment: `$scope.filter($scope.filter($scope.inventories` seems so strange :D

Comment: A for-loop for filtering is also strange. You could also do a single filter return item.barcode = B && item.manufacturer = M but I would prefer chaining them.